# r"""What does it mean?"""

Tags: python, pytorch

I see `r"""` followed by a comment in quite a few of the source codes for `PyTorch` and the one I am looking at is [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html). What is the `r` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `r` in front of a string makes it a raw string literal. In short it means that any `\` in that string will not be seen as an escape character, like when you write `\n` for newline.

Some more info can be found here:
[What exactly do “u” and “r” string flags do, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)

Comment: Thanks, was hard to google because kept getting results about R the programing language.